# How can I vertically center a span that takes up 2 rows with an adjacent column that only takes up 1 row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a picture of my issue.  I want the `Live` span to be centered with the 2 date pickers.

[image]

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0xmhaca/).

And the code:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6"><span>Live</span></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" max-date="'2016-9-26'" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="start_dt" is-open="open['start_dt']" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('start_dt')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" max-date="'2016-9-26'" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="end_dt" is-open="open['end_dt']" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-gray btn-default" ng-click="open('end_dt')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
            </p>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Assign `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to your `.row`.

**CSS**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0xmhaca/1/)**

**Note*** You might want to give that `.row` div a unique class and assign the properties to it.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is a what I would have suggested but browser support isn't that great for it. You could just add some padding to the `span`

`span.add-padding {
  padding: 24px 0;
  display:inline-block; 
}`

`<span class="add-padding">Live</span>`

https://jsfiddle.net/mikeilk/0dsbvhhu/

Comment: obviously adjust the amount of padding to suit your other styling.